# Netbeans IDE : Injection point

Tags: netbeans, cdi

In a class of my Web / JEE project, I wanted to add an annotation: @Inject from CDI.
But since, I have at the beginning of the line a round with an "i" inside with bubble info: "Injection point".
How to remove this point? The class file is in error, but without any error description !!!.
Thank you very much for your help because my project is stopped.

Comment: A blue circle with an 'i' and a "Injection point" bubble is normal. If you click on it, NetBeans jumps to that injected item.

Comment: @Inject is from CDI, not JSF

Comment: Ok but the class file error ? An idea ?

Comment: Why don't you just try and execute build? If there is any error, it should pop into your console.

Comment: It works well. thank you very much